# Nav Link - Coloured Background

Tags: css, wordpress

I am looking to customize navigation bar on my wordpress site to have a Surrounding colour for a 'Get a demo' Menu, you can have a look at website in the below link

https://www.punchtab.com/

How can i achieve the same in my WordPress site?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Gareth

Comment: Yoou can achieve this by using css..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding `background-color: #DC286D;` to the `header-login-nav` in the css.

```
#header-login-nav 
{
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #DC286D;
}
```

So on your wordpress site, you would need to change it on the navigation class/id (it would depend on your theme).

EDIT:

```
#menu-main-menu 
{
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Howlin, thanks for your response! I have looked into the Style.CSS file in the Themes folder but it has hardly any code actually in it, is there another one I should be looking at? Sorry i'm still getting to grips with this. my site is here: www.theloyaltycloud.com if it makes it easier to look at

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can change the `#000` to the colour that you want it to be.

Comment: Howlin, thanks for your answer, I still cannot figure this out, i've tried inspecting the element on www.theloyaltycloud.com but I cannot get this to work

Comment: I have edit my post again. Try adding that to the end of the styles.css file

Comment: Howlin thanks for your answer, I cannot find the correct style.css file, where should it be located if I am using wordpress? I am really struggling with this

Comment: Wheb you login to WordPress, go to Appearance -> Editor. Then scroll down to the bottom. On the bottom right hand side of the screen you will see Styles.css. click on that and go to the bottom of that svreen add the code in my post into it.

Comment: Hi Howlin,all the css file says is below: /* Theme Name: Angle
 * Theme URI: http://themes.oxygenna.com/angle
 * Description: Angle Theme
 * Version: 1.4.0
 * Author: Oxygenna.com
 * Author URI: http://www.oxygenna.com
 * Tags: responsive-layout, blue, brown, red, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-menu, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, post-formats, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
 * License: envato marketplace licence
 * License URI: http://wiki.envato.com/support/legal-terms/licensing-terms/
 */

Comment: Add the `#menu-main-menu { background-color: #000 !important; }` style to the bottom of that file.