# navigation background colour

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to change the 'Get A Demo' (menu-item-382) on the nav to have a square colored background around it (#3EAABD).

This is the code using the inspect element tool:

```
<header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top swatch-red-white text-caps" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"></div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="menu-sidebar pull-right"></div>
            <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
                <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="menu-item-342" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page cur… page-item-215 current_page_item menu-item-342 active active"></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-283" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-283"></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-282" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-282"></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-278"></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-329" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-329"></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-382" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-382">
                        <a href="http://theloyaltycloud.com/demo/" title="Get A Demo"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

How can I do this and where is the correct style.css file located on my Wordpress site theloyaltycloud.com) for me to edit it?

At the moment the style css file only says this:

```
/* Theme Name: Angle
 * Theme URI: ///
 * Description: Angle Theme
 * Version: 1.4.0
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * Tags: responsive-layout, blue, brown, red, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-menu, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, post-formats, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
 * License: envato marketplace licence
 */
```

Hope this makes sense as i'm dying over here trying to do it,

Many thanks everyone,

Gareth

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nav Link - Coloured Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860883/nav-link-coloured-background)

Answer (score 0):

Change your css file to this:

```
/* Theme Name: Angle
 * Theme URI: ///
 * Description: Angle Theme
 * Version: 1.4.0
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: 
 * Tags: responsive-layout, blue, brown, red, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-menu,     featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, post-formats, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready
 * License: envato marketplace licence
 */

#menu-item-382 
{
    background-color: #3EAABD;
}
```

That will only change the background colour of that menu option to that colour

Comment: I have changed this but it doesn't seem to have altered it

Comment: Can you see a `theme.css` file?

Comment: There is no theme.css file by the look of it

Comment: It's ok I have solved it! It seems as though there was an Advanced section under the theme option in Wordpress which allowed me to do add in "Extra CSS (loaded last in the header)", so it overrides the default css, thanks for all your help Howlin! I appreciate your time and effort

Comment: Cool, that was going to be my next suggestion! Good luck :)